# Rounded border used as progress bar?

Tags: html, css, progress

I have created 4 blocks, and over that in the middle goes a circle with transparent background and with a border. How could it be possible to make that border a progress bar? Or is there a way to make the border grow? For example only 40% of the border is colored, rest is other color? 
Here is my current HTML/CSS code

```css
            .block {
              width: 200px;
              height: 200px;
              background-color: purple;
              display: inline-block;
              margin-right: 10px;
              margin-top: 10px;
              position:relative;
              z-index: -1;
            }
            .circle {
              width: 140px;
              height: 140px;
              background: transparent;
              border: 40px solid orange;
              position: absolute;
              z-index: 1;
              margin-left: 95px;
              margin-top: 110px;
              border-radius: 50%;
              -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 53px -13px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 53px -13px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 53px -13px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
            }
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <body>
    </body>
    <div class="blocks">
      <div class="circle">
      </div>
    <div class="block">
    </div>
    <div class="block">
    </div><br />
    <div class="block">
    </div>
    <div class="block">
    </div></div>
    </body>
```

Comment: http://www.cssscript.com/demo/pure-css-circular-percentage-bar/

Comment: @SahilDhir "Download" seems a bit dodgy - why not just show the code on the page?

Comment: Hope you get the answer. as this question has been marked as duplicate

Comment: @SahilDhir this circular percentage bar could work if I could figure out how it works. CSS is a mess to figure it out.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly could not find a topic on this so started this one. Ill check that topic out.

Comment: as this question is marked .. So I won't be able to answer :(